# JAVA Socket communication Client -> Server -> Client

Tags: java, sockets, stream

So I have this little java project about chatting..

I am able to create a Threaded server and able to connect and communicated with the server using input and output streams.

Now my problem is that if a second client enters the Server I want the first client to be able to communicate with the second client vice-versa.. **Also** if a third client is connected to the server I don't want the third client to be able to communicated the the first and second clients.

How can I do it??

Comment: You would need to add the concept of "room" to your application, and for every client you need to have either a preconfigured set of rooms available for the client or ask the client which room it wants to get connected with. Other solution would be to add the concept of "contact list" (like Skype) and allow your clients to "see" only other clients in the client's list.

Answer (score 0):

Use some array of list to hold your clients and then for a `user` you can do

```
if (list.indexOf (user) == 0 || list.indexOf (user) == 1) {
    if (list.indexOf (sendto) == 0 || list.indexOf (sendto) == 1) {
        // chat OK
    }
}
```